# How to sync django calendar project with mobile app calendar?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, android-calendar

I have created a calendar with drf and react js which has all calendar features including events.
Now, I'm trying to see my calendars and events on mobile calendar apps like Samsung or iphone calendar.
I use google to authenticate users. Is there any ways to do it?
What if I use my own email service (something other than google account)?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so if you're asking how can you sync your calendar app (which you made using drf and react) data with apps like google calendars. You can do that via their API services. These API services offer you to read and update calendars with several popular programming languages, such as Java, JavaScript, and Python. I hope that answers your question.

Here's the link to the documentation - [Google Calenders API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api)

Comment: Actually I want to see my calendars in my mobile phone, eg my samsung calendar. Is there anyway to do it?